# Migrations in stand alone Django app

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-south

How do I makemigrations on a stand alone Django app (ie one that is not part if any project).

For example after following: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/reusable-apps/

Answer (score 11):

You can do it similar to how you do testing scripts for apps:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import django

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.management import call_command

settings.configure(DEBUG=True,
    INSTALLED_APPS=(
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'your_app',
    ),
)

django.setup()
call_command('makemigrations', 'your_app')
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to create a mock project, containing only that app, then the process is as usual:

```
manage.py makemigrations myapp
```